# Why deviates in opengl the gl_FragCoord.z from the depth buffer one?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-3.0

I have been trying for some time to find a way to read the depth value for a particular mouse coordinate (x, y). Everything works fine on win10 with opengl 4.x, but not for opengl es 3.x

My approaches:

1. glReadPixels() does not work on openGL es for depth buffer
2. ray cast is not suitable because I work with a large terrain model
3. subsequent method would suffice, but unfortunately too inaccurate, also on win10 but why?

   ```
   #version 420
   uniform vec2 screenXy;
   uniform vec2 screenSize;

   out vec4 fragColor;

   void main(void) {

   if((int(gl_FragCoord.x) == int(screenXy.x)) && ((int(screenSize.y) - int(gl_FragCoord.y)) == int(screenXy.y))) {
       fragColor.r = gl_FragCoord.z;
       } else {
           fragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1.0);
       }
   }
   ```

I submit the mouse xy coordinates to the fragementshader (screenXy). If the clicked pixel is in the row, I write the depth value in the color buffer. This works, but the value gl_FragCoord.z and the one from the depth buffer are not exactly the same (I know this one from the depth buffer is correct). Although gl_FragCoord.z and the depth buffer value is float, and so I think 32bit.

```
GLfloat zd; // from depth buffer
GLfloat zc[4]; // from color buffer
m_func->glReadPixels(xy.x(), m_pFbo->height() - xy.y(), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &zd);
m_func->glReadPixels(xy.x(), m_pFbo->height() - xy.y(), 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, zc);
```

Reasons:

1. the deviation occurs through an internal type conversion, but where?
2. because the GL_DEPTH_TEST is executed after the fragmentshader gl_FragCoord.z is not the closest one (to the camera), but which is saved in the depth buffer. So it would also make no sense to save gl_FragCoord.z in a separat Frambuffer, because its not the correct value.

Can maybe someone help me and solve the knot, because I can not find any other explanation?

Here some measured values:

```
zc  0.984314
zd  0.985363

zc  0.552941
zd  0.554653

zc  1 -> extremly critical
zd  0.999181
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 0.984314 * 255.0 is exactly 251.0, I assume the internal format of the color plane is `GL_RGBA8`. That means there is 1 byte for each color channel and `zc` can only have 256 different values, from 0.0 to 1.0 in steps of 1/256.

If it is supported by the OpenGL ES version which you use, then you can change the format of the render buffer storage (e,g. `GL_R32F` - only red color channel, but 32 bit floating point).

Or you can encode the depth to the 4 channels of the 4 * 8 bit color plane:

```
vec4 PackDepth( in float depth )
{
    depth *= (256.0*256.0*256.0 - 1.0) / (256.0*256.0*256.0);
    vec4 encode = fract( depth * vec4(1.0, 256.0, 256.0*256.0, 256.0*256.0*256.0) );
    return vec4( encode.xyz - encode.yzw / 256.0, encode.w ) + 1.0/512.0;
}

....

fragColor = PackDepth(gl_FragCoord.z);
```

And you can decode it after reading the value:

```
GLfloat zc[4]; // from color buffer
m_func->glReadPixels(xy.x(), m_pFbo->height() - xy.y(), 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, zc);

float depth = zc[0] + zc[1]/256.0 + zc[2]/(256.0*256.0) + zc[3]/(256.0*256.0*256.0);
depth = depth * (255.0f/256.0f) * (256.0*256.0*256.0) / (256.0*256.0*256.0 - 1.0);
```

Comment: Just to answer the "if it's supported" comment - float framebuffers are only core functionality only in OpenGL ES 3.2, but are available via an extension on some earlier OpenGL ES 3.0 GPUs.

Comment: @Rabbid76: So far, I have tried 4 different decodeFloat32ToRgba8 algorithms, unfortunately all are lossy. The only one that is exact for small values is https://aras-p.info/blog/2009/07/30/encoding-floats-to-rgba-the-final/ but if z is close to 1, then this too fails. And GL_R32F does not exist, only GL_RED (also opengl 4.x) and that is only 8bit.

Comment: Unfortunately not precise enough. The best one is in the link above. But the result is not really understandable. This works 80% exactly regardless of the size of the value. Then suddenly a kind of overflow. Here some results:

zc  0.485301
zd  0.485301

zc  0.999121
zd  0.999121

zc  1.00394
zd  0.998262

It's always if one of the rgba values reaches 1. e.g. for the last value rgba = (1, 1, 1, 0).

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know with certainty whether gl_FragCoord.z is the same as in the depth buffer after the depth test. With a counter you could make a query

```
if(gl_FragCoord.z_last > gl_FragCoord.z)
    fragColor.z = gl_FragCoord.z;
```

so basically what the depth test does. but how does one store gl_FragCoord.z_last as static? Is there a way lossless to read the depth value in openGL 3.x? According to solidpixel there is a float framebuffer only from opengl 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems so that the value in the depth buffer is not exactly the same as gl_FragCoord.z. I think the following example demonstrates it.

```
#version 420

uniform vec4 color;
uniform vec2 screenXy;
uniform vec2 screenSize;

in vec2 vBC;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main(void) {

fragColor.r = gl_FragCoord.z;

}
```

C++

```
GLfloat zd;
GLubyte zc[4];
m_func->glReadPixels(xy.x(), m_pFbo->height() - xy.y(), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &zd);
m_func->glReadPixels(xy.x(), m_pFbo->height() - xy.y(), 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, zc);
```

Data:
    zc0 = 255 (from gl_FragCoord.z);
    zd = 0.996561 (from depth buffer)

But it should be 254, because 0.996561 * 255 = 254.123055.